# Failed to parse JSON data and bind in table using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-ng-repeat

basically i am tring to bind my json result in html table but getting below mention error:

```
     "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=req%20in%20requiterTable&p1=string%3A%22&p2=%22
N/<@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:412
Je</<.compile/</<@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:302:477
vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$watchCollection/<@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:142:77
vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:143:181
vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:146:111
l@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:97:320
J@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:102:34
gg/</t.onload@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:103:4
EventHandlerNonNull*gg/<@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:102:343
n@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:99:53
m/p<@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:96:262
e/<@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:131:20
vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:145:343
vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:142:412
vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:146:111
EventHandlerNonNull*gg/<@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:102:343
n@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:99:53
m/p<@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:96:262
e/<@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:131:20
vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:145:343
vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:142:412
vf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:146:111
Bc/c/<@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:20:486
h/<.invoke@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:41:454
Bc/c@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:20:407
Bc@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:21:179
fe@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:20:1
@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:317:386
b@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:189:487
Sf@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:37:125
Rf/d@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:37:74
EventListener.handleEvent*.on/h@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:195:22
.on@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:195:108
O.prototype[b]@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:198:332
O.prototype.ready@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:190:40
@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:317:355
@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:2
```

Below is my JS service which returns the json result as i mentioned

```
app.service('RequitersService', function ($http) {
    this.GetAllRquiters = function ()
    {
        return $http.get("api/Requiters");
    }
});
```

Json result:

```
"[{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Amit\",\"email\":\"amit@gmail.com\",\"mobile\":\"9999999999\",\"skill\":\"Asp.net\",\"profession\":\"Software Engineer\",\"exp\":\"2\",\"location\":\"Delhi\",\"resume\":null,\"is_type\":null,\"is_active\":false,\"last_login\":\"Jul 5 2016 4:49PM\",\"date_time\":null}]"
```

my ng controller code:

```
app.controller('Requiters', function ($scope, RequitersService) {
    var result = RequitersService.GetAllRquiters();
    result.then(function (x) {
        debugger;
        alert(x.data);
        $scope.requiterTable = x.data;
    });
});
```

below is my html page code which is giving the error  in console

```
<table >
    <tr ng-repeat="req in requiterTable">
        <td>{{req.id}}</td>
        <td>{{req.name}}</td>
        <td>{{req.email}}</td>
        <td>{{req.mobile}}</td>
        <td>{{req.location}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `track by` to help angular differentiate objects and track changes:

```
<tr ng-repeat="req in requiterTable track by req.id">
```

Comment: no its giving the same problem and i think something wrong while parsing or binding data in html table

Comment: can you change your angular script from minified version to a regular one? we can better understand the console error this way

Comment: i have changed n getting this error:                   "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: req in requiterTable track by req.id, Duplicate key: undefined, Duplicate value: {
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=req%20in%20requiterTable%20track%20by%20req.id&p1=undefined&p2=%7B
minErr/<@http://localhost:56557/Scripts/angular.js:68:12

Comment: i think problem in my JSON result

Comment: "[{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Amit\",\"email\":\"amit@gmail.com\",\"mobile\":\"9999999999\",\"skill\":\"Asp.net\",\"profession\":\"Software Engineer\",\"exp\":\"2\",\"location\":\"Delhi\",\"resume\":null,\"is_type\":null,\"is_active\":false,\"last_login\":\"Jul 5 2016 4:49PM\",\"date_time\":null}]"

Comment: It looks like an array of one object only. can you console.log(requiterTable)?